# C++ convert unordered_map to unordered_set without rehashing

Tags: c++, stl, hashmap, unordered-map, unordered-set

Is there a way, in C++20, to convert an `unordered_map` to an `unordered_set` when both have the same hashing function ?

Looping over one, and inserting to the other, would rehash the same keys again. I want to avoid this if I can.

The only way I can think of, is a custom Hash function with memoization / caching. But this also introduces different costs. Is there another way ?

Comment: Do you just want to drop the values?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Dropping the values is a consideration. Changing the value type is another. So the use case can also be `unordered_map<key, Type1>` to `unordered_map<key, Type2>`. When storing both `Type1` and `Type2` is infeasible.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use the keys or values in the unordered_map for the set?  If it's the keys, then just use the new contains method in C++ 20 to see if the key exists or find in C++ 11 instead of storing the keys in a separate container.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The need to store the keys in a separate container is indeed a rare thing, however is not a part of the question. I know I can use the keys directly from the first container.